# While it runs it skips over if and disregards my if conditional. Why and Fix?

Tags: bash, shell

My code is here. You don't have to worry about the second while though. It the exact same just player 2 instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
#this is a game that is two player and it is a race to get to 
#100 before the other player

echo "Player 1 name?"
read p1
echo "Player 2 name?"
read p2
echo "Okay $p1 and $p2. $p1 will go first"
p1s=0
p2s=0
pt=1

while [ $pt == 1 ]; do
echo "roll or stay"
read choice

if [ $choice == r ]; then

die=$(($RANDOM%6+1))

elif [ $die -eq 1 ]; then
p1s=$(echo "$p1s-$count" |bc)
echo "You rolled a 1. Your score is $p1s"
echo "$p2 turn now."
sleep 1
count=0
pt=2

elif [ $die > 1 ]; then
p1s=$(echo "$p1s+$die" |bc)
count=$(echo "$count+$die" |bc)
echo "You rolled a $die. Your score is $p1s"
pt=1

else

if [ $choice == s ]; then
echo "Okay $p1 your score is $p1s"
echo "$p2 turn now"
sleep 1
count=0
pt=2

else

pt=1

fi
fi

if [ $p1s > 99 ]; then
echo "$p1 won. $p2 lost"
echo "would you like to play again?"
read again
elif [ $again == yes ]; then
echo "Okay one second."
sleep 1
clear
bash num.sh
elif [ $again == no ]; then
echo "ok going back to the games directory then"
sleep 1
bash games.sh

fi

done

while [ $pt == 2 ]; do
echo "roll or stay"
read choice
if [ $choice == r ]; then

die=$(($RANDOM%6+1))

elif [ $die -eq 1 ]; then
p1s=$(echo "$p2s-$count" |bc)
echo "You rolled a 1. Your score is $p2s"
echo "$p1 turn now."
sleep 1
count=0
pt=2

elif [ $die > 1 ]; then
p1s=$(echo "$p2s+$die" |bc)
count=$(echo "$count+$die" |bc)
echo "You rolled a $die. Your score is $p2s"
pt=1

else

if [ $choice == s ]; then
echo "Okay $p1 your score is $p2s"
echo "$p1 turn now"
sleep 1
count=0
pt=2

else

pt=2

fi
fi

if [ $p2s > 99 ]; then
echo "$p2 won. $p1 lost"
echo "would you like to play again?"
read again
elif [ $again == yes ]; then
echo "Okay one second."
sleep 1
clear
bash num.sh
elif [ $again == no ]; then
echo "ok going back to the games directory then"
sleep 1
bash games.sh

fi

done
```

What happens after I run it is this

```
Player 1 name?
name1
Player 2 name?
name2
Okay name1 and name2. name1 will go first
roll or stay
r
name1 won. name2 lost
would you like to play again?
```

It is supposed to roll and you get a random number if one then the score for that round is deleted and goes to next player. If you roll a 2-6 it adds to that rounds score. if you stay then you save your score and each rounds score add up till one player gets 100 points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test comparison operators you are using to test numeric relations are wrong. For example:

`elif [ $die > 1 ]; then` should be ----> `elif [ $die -gt 1 ]; then`

`if [ $p2s > 99 ]; then` should be ----> `if [ $p2s -gt 99 ]; then`

and so on.

Here are the list of test comparison operators for numeric values:

- `==` ---> `-eq` (equals)
- `!=` ---> `-ne` (not equals)
- `>` ---> `-gt` (greater than)
- `<` ---> `-lt` (less than)
- `>=` ---> `-ge` (greater or equal to)
- `<=` ---> `-le` (lesser or equal to)

Comment: it seems now it says                                               Player 1 name?
g
Player 2 name?
g
Okay g and g. g will go first
roll or stay
r
num.sh: line 54: [: ==: unary operator expected
num.sh: line 59: [: ==: unary operator expected
roll or stay
these are the if you want to play again do they need -eq even though they are yes and no not a numerical value

Comment: ok i have taken that out and it now works. thankyou very much.